# Animation-Direction in older version of Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to make some animations compatible with older version of Chrome, specifically 37.0.2062.94 (which is used inside of OBS - a streaming/recording software).

On newer versions of Chrome, everything works great.  However, on these older versions, the animation fades in, but the reverse animation does not work.  Perhaps animation-direction: reverse?  I have tried vendor prefixes etc. as best as I can.

So I'd like to either:

1) Make this method work inside of old Chrome with the CSS animation

or

2) Use JQuery to simulate a fade out effect, making sure it is compatible with older versions of Chrome

[Here is a link to the JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ydtpjuyg/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one" class="box"></div>
    <div id="two" class="box"></div>
    <div id="three" class="box"></div>
    <div id="four" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #one {
        background: black;
    }
    #two {
        background: blue;
    }
    #three {
        background: green;
    }
    #four {
        background: red;
    }

    .box {
        margin: 10px;
    }

    .box.animate {
        animation: box .4s ease-in;
        -webkit-animation: box .4s ease-in;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        display: block;
    }
    .box.animate.reverse {
        animation-direction: reverse;
        -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
    }
        @keyframes box {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(-10px,-10px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(0px,0px);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes box {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-10px,-10px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    }
}
```

JS

```
var $boxes = $('.box');

(function animateBox(i) {
    $boxes.eq(i).addClass('animate').one('animationend', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(this).hide().show(0).addClass('reverse').one('animationend', function () {
                $(this).removeClass('animate');
                if(++i < $boxes.length) setTimeout(animateBox, 1000, i); // pause between animations
            });
        }.bind(this), 2000); // how long animation stays on
    });
})(0);
```

Comment: Have you tried transform: translate(0px, 0px) in the final keyframe ?

Comment: I think making the entire CSS animation the time I need it, and doing something like you recommend is a way to fix it.  Meaning I hand code the reverse animation, instead of just using animation-direction.

Comment: It should be compatible with Chrome 19+, so this should work (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction#Browser_compatibility). Try to reverse the order (put prefixes first and then the actual final implementation, thats how its usually done.)